# Python Seleniumdriver get NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nonetype

I would like to ask if anyone knows why they tell me that the driver is a NoneType, below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_site(endpoint):
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver = driver.get(endpoint)
  return driver

def get_logged(driver):
  
  try:
    inputUser = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
  finally:
    driver.quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
  url = "https://logon.fastweb.it/oam/server/obrareq.cgi?encquery%3D1%2FGW5uB%2Bh4bKAKj%2FPYv8lCcoHT7AvYWgpoiTqOAaltkzLYb0%2BCJWw7yAeIR4JSsd9lNz4QgZbaGY%2B0We0nqu0pzODI8foO7KuGl9XoXnEEPpiOt2pgZLIy%2FsuuZT8sG6mYgWEFJ3SjumdY0Vxy27q8cab8%2BgapLT85otLP3Zv5bKdIkJ6aRxZLMvg8JU5ZpXtPYn2icoJSpGBDDmUZaxewYunYeMJ0%2Bhgu9%2FdieDYP44N4QIV642dgpsZPs%2Bv3kkEYZDasbOJkQt0ZXQnQWqM%2BZnKMS7EMF2ddeYwBDqaKbg4qEqp5RIASYNNijg7D%2F8%20agentid%3DFront-End-OAM%20ver%3D1%20crmethod%3D2"
  driver = get_site(url)
  get_logged(driver)
```

and the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    get_logged(driver)
  File "main.py", line 16, in get_logged
    driver.quit()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: The way you're handling the driver is very peculiar. I'd probably refactor this to use a class...

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way you're handling Selenium.

Selenium should not be passed around your functions like a typical HTTP request, it is a standalone driver that you are operating with code.

For example, `driver = driver.get(url)` does not return a driver, in fact it returns nothing, because all you're doing with `driver.get()` is telling your webdriver to navigate to a specific link. This is the root of your `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'` because the new `driver` variable you've defined is the result of `driver.get()`, which is nothing.

I've gone ahead and refactored your code (untested) to a class approach, this should be a much cleaner way to tackle your problem.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class DriverController():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    
    def get_site(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
    
    def get_logged(self):
        try:
            inputUser = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
        finally:
            self.driver.quit()


url = "https://logon.fastweb.it/oam/server/obrareq.cgi?encquery%3D1%2FGW5uB%2Bh4bKAKj%2FPYv8lCcoHT7AvYWgpoiTqOAaltkzLYb0%2BCJWw7yAeIR4JSsd9lNz4QgZbaGY%2B0We0nqu0pzODI8foO7KuGl9XoXnEEPpiOt2pgZLIy%2FsuuZT8sG6mYgWEFJ3SjumdY0Vxy27q8cab8%2BgapLT85otLP3Zv5bKdIkJ6aRxZLMvg8JU5ZpXtPYn2icoJSpGBDDmUZaxewYunYeMJ0%2Bhgu9%2FdieDYP44N4QIV642dgpsZPs%2Bv3kkEYZDasbOJkQt0ZXQnQWqM%2BZnKMS7EMF2ddeYwBDqaKbg4qEqp5RIASYNNijg7D%2F8%20agentid%3DFront-End-OAM%20ver%3D1%20crmethod%3D2"

dc = DriverController()
dc.get_site(url)
dc.get_logged()
```